# Sitecore: Programmatically Exit Edit Mode in Page Editor

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, page-editor

When in Sitecore's Page Editor mode clicks the Edit button, I have a DIV's style set to

```
 top: 0;
```

so that it appears on top of the Page Editor buttons (Save, Save and Close, Insert, etc..). This div prevents the content editor from using the normal Page Editor buttons and forces them to use the custom Save, Save and Close, and Close buttons that I have added to the DIV.

Is there a way to programmatically  exit Edit mode whenever they click on my custom Close or Save and Close button? I do not want to log them out of the Page Editor (just exit them out of edit mode). I only have 1 page where I am doing this, so I would rather not get into changing configurations in Sitecore to achieve this.

Answer (score 4):

Check out this post: [In Sitecore, how to change or set PageMode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13712832/in-sitecore-how-to-change-or-set-pagemode)

It looks like you can do:

```
Context.Site.SetDisplayMode(Sitecore.Sites.DisplayMode.Normal, Sitecore.Sites.DisplayModeDuration.ResetAfterRequest);
```

Or, you can add `sc_mode=normal` or `sc_mode=preview` to the URL's query string.